# Faster way to implement this formula in python

Tags: python, optimization

`n` and `F` are 3d matrices of dimensions `m * l * l`, where `m`=5 and `l`=174. `n` is given by gamma multiplied by the square of norm 2 of Fi-Fj. [Formula here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPFri.png) 
My current brute force implementation is

```
for k in range(0,m):
  for i in range(0,l):
    for j in range(0,l):
      dist = gamma*(np.linalg.norm(F[0][i] - F[0][j]))
      m3.append(dist)
    m2.append(m3)
  m1.append(m2)
```

But my program crashes. Is there an optimized way to compute this?

Comment: What's the crash? Are you time or memory constrained?

Comment: time constrained

Comment: Perhaps you could use the Python multiprocessing library to do this in parallel? E.g. set up a process for each value of the 5 values of `k`, then combine the results.

Answer (score 1):

Right now your operation is done using 3 nested slow Python-style loops. Use the power of Numpy, broadcasting along the last-but-one axis and vectorizing the operations:

```
n = gamma * np.sum((F[:,np.newaxis,:,:] - F[:,:,np.newaxis,:])**2, axis=-1)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of F in your code? I get 'list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple' error.

Comment: `F` should be a Numpy array, not a Python list. Add `F = np.array(F)` before the line